# Split a string with space and bracket

Tags: python, string, split

I have some coordinates in form of

```
coordinate = (2.50 6.50)
```

I want it should split like

```
2.50:6.50
```

I have used `coordinate.split(" ")`. But don't know how to use it properly to get above line.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function.

So Try this:

```
coordinate = (2.50, 6.50)
print "{}:{}".format(*coordinate)
```

Output:

```
2.5:6.5
```

Answer (score 1):

K DawG's answer is good if you have them directly as tuples.

If you have them as a string `coord = '(2.50 6.50)'`, you can parse it like this:

```
'(2.50 6.50)'.strip("()").split(' ')
```

And then, using his formatting:

```
>>> coord = '(2.50 6.50)'
>>> '{}:{}'.format(*coord.strip("()").split(' '))
'2.50:6.50'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since coordinate is a string as:

```
coordinate = '(2.50 6.50)'
```

Apart from val's answer you can do this also:

```
print("{0}:{1}").format(*coordinate[1:-1:].split())
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if it's actually a string you can just go with:

```
coordinate.strip("()").replace(' ', ':')
```

which will get the output you wanted.

you can read more about strings in the docs
http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html